# Is there a way to define liveness probe API in Spring in a different port than the main one, while keeping the readiness probe in the default port?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

We are in the process of adding readiness/liveness probes to our backend servers.
We are using Spring & Actuator and want to implement it using the actuator built in implementation.
We noticed that in a stress load on our environment, our current API for liveness (custom made) takes a long time to respond and eventually our pod is getting killed by the liveness probe.

We want to be able to move a under load pod out of the ready pool using the readiness probe.
but we don't want the pod to get terminated if we are having high latency to our response times.

Now in order to keep the liveness alive, we understood that we need to give a different port for the actuator as it will give the readiness/liveness api's different thread pool so the liveness will stay alive.

But, the readiness api will not check anymore our main thread pool, which means we can have not functioning pod, but with readiness/liveness that return status OK.

How can we move only the liveness probe to a separate port?

From the documentation  [https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-actuator.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

We tried to use managment.server.port , and expected that it will solve our problem.
but it's actually also moves the readiness probe

is there a way to only move liveness to a different thread pool?

thank you